# How can I select the same set of characters that occur in multiple non-contiguous lines, then copy those entire marked lines to a new Notepad?

Tags: character, notepad++, unique

I have 3 characters "(CE" appearing in 1,000's of lines but not every one. How do I select all lines with that set of characters, then copy the entire set of lines out to a new Notepad ++?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the "**Mark**" tab of the search/replace dialogue, or use menu => **Search** => **Mark...**. Ensure that "**Bookmark line**" is selected. Enter the required search string, and click on "**Mark all**". The lines containing the search string should now be highlighted with blue circles on their left. Now use menu => **Search** => **Bookmark** => **Copy bookmarked lines** and then do a paste into a new buffer and save. The menu entries also show you the keyboard combinations, if any, that do the same tasks.